# How does dom_id and dom_class work in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Can anyone give a brief explaination on how `dom_id` and `dom_class` work in rails ? and when on what scenarios can we think of using it. I could not find anything on it , even in [ApiDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/RecordIdentifier/dom_id).

Is it specific to rails only?

Answer (score 10):

`dom_id` and `dom_class` are helper methods you can use in your HTML to get consistent html id attributes and class attributes for objects.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-dom_id

As an example, you might want to do the following in an index page:

```
<ul>
  <%= @accounts.each do |account| %>
    <li id="<%= dom_id(account) %>">
      <%= account.title %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_account_path(account), class: dom_class(account, :edit) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This will give you a list where each `li` tag has an id in the format of `account_X` where X is the ActiveRecord ID. You can use this ID then for javascript, etc to target the right elements.

In addition, the code above would give each edit link a class of `edit_account` if you want styling or selection of those common elements.

Answer (score 6):

I've never used this, or seen it used. And if you look at the source on the link you provided you will see `ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn(INSTANCE_MESSAGE % 'dom_id')`, which kind of gives the impression that you should not use these methods.

However, it looks like if you look up the ActionView equivalent (which is called by the one you linked) then there is some documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-dom_id

These also look like they're not deprecated.

Comment: FYI, these methods are still available in [Rails 7.0.4.2](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-dom_class).